# Font used in 'Home Team: Global Domination' game board?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

The territory names are very small, no results with 'WhatTheFont!'.

[image]

Comment: The reason that you don't get results is most likely because the image is way too small and blurry. Which will hinder people here just as much.

Comment: Agreed - if you could find a higher resolution scan that'd be quite helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The oceans are easy: that's Lucida Blackletter (stretched). The country names look very similar to "FinalRoman Medium", but that doesn't have a capital P like yours. However it would be a decent match if the right font can't be identified.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 because you the only one who helped. But it's clearly not the same font so I will not accept it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

This is killing me, I know that font. The only name that is coming to mind is Frutiger's [**Ondine**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/ondine/). Not quite it but it has a lot of the qualities you're going for.

[image]

If the match comes to me, I'll update here. It's going to keep me awake tonight!

*UPDATE*

[**Pompeijana**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/pompeijana/) comes closer in some respects. Maybe this is what I had in mind, but the `G` isn't right, among other details.

[image]

[image]

*UPDATE TO THE UPDATE*

I just had to go look one more time, following the Pompeijana thread. I know this also is not a perfect match but it is closer in some respects: [**Pompeii Caps**](http://www.ffonts.net/Pompeii-Caps.font?text=East%20africa%20congo). It's not as well drawn as Pompeijana but it is free!
[image]